# Download Manager notification not showing when downloading a file

Tags: android, kotlin, notifications

I have an application where i have a feature to download a file already stored in firebase. i have implemented the code to download using download manager and at the same time show the user the notification of downloading that file but for some reason it is not working.

This is my code

```
val downloadRequest = DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(model.document.substringBeforeLast(".")))
downloadRequest.setTitle("الملف")
downloadRequest.setDescription("تحميل الملف")
downloadRequest.setVisibleInDownloadsUi(true)
downloadRequest.setDestinationUri(uri.toUri())
downloadRequest.allowScanningByMediaScanner()
downloadRequest.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
downloadManager.enqueue(downloadRequest)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the file getting downloaded but notification is not visible or file is not getting downloaded either?

try this and let me know if it still doesn't work :)

```
downloadRequest.setNotificationVisibility(
DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE
)
```

EDIT

it seems that the last time I used it there was a difference in the destination that you are specifying.

```
val directory: File = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().path + "/myFile")

    if(!directory.exists()) {
        directory.mkdir()
    }

...

downloadRequest.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("/myFile","android")
```

Comment: I will verify your answer and let you know

Comment: i can store the file but the problem is still with the notification that dosn't show up when downloading the file

Comment: did you try it on an emulator like `Google Pixel`? It might be an issue that your `OS` is blocking the `notifications` like some devices do in `battery saving` mode?